# Count the frequency of a Character in a Word

Tags: java, string

Raji wants to count the no of occurrences of the given character.Write a program to accept a word from the user. Get a character from the user and find the no of occurrences .

Check whether the given character and word is valid

The word is valid if it contains only alphabets and no space or any special characters or numbers.

The character is valid if it is an alphabet alone.

Sample Input 1:
Enter a word:
programming
Enter the character:
m

Sample Output 1:

No of 'm' present in the given word is 2.

Sample Input 2:
Enter a word:
programming
Enter the character:
s

Sample Output 2:

The given character 's' not present in the given word.

Sample Input 3:
Enter a word:
56
Sample Output 3:

Not a valid string

Sample Input 4:
Enter a word:
Hello
Enter the character:
6

Sample Output 4:

Given character is not an alphabet

Am getting an error:
Failed tests:
Test 3: Check the logic when character is not present and word is in capital

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  What have you been able to code?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work. Although i am unable pass one test case, But feel free to try this it may work for you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class OccurrenceOfChar{
   public static void main (String[] args) {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          int n[] = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},flag=0;
          System.out.println("Enter a word:");
          String input = in.nextLine();
          input=input.toLowerCase();
          for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
        if(((int)input.charAt(i)-97)<0 || ((int)input.charAt(i)-97)>25){
            flag=1;
        }
        else{
            n[(int)input.charAt(i)-97]++;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        System.out.println("Not a valid string");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Enter the character:");
        String t = in.nextLine();
        String s=t.toLowerCase();
        if(((int)s.charAt(0)-97)<0 || ((int)s.charAt(0)-97)>25){
            System.out.println("Given character is not an alphabet");
        }
        else{
            if(n[(int)s.charAt(0)-97]>0){
                System.out.println("No of\'"+s+"\' present in the given word is "+n[(int)s.charAt(0)-97]+".");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The given character \'"+s+"\' not present in the given word.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class OccurrenceOfChar { 
public static int count(String s, char c) 
{ 
    int res = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) 
    { 
        if (s.charAt(i) == c) 
        res++; 
    } 
    return res; 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");  
  
    String str= sc.nextLine();  
if(Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$",str) && (!str.isEmpty())){
    
    System.out.print("Enter the character: ");  
    char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
    
    if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
        
    if( str.indexOf(c)==-1){
        System.out.println("The given character '"+c+"' not present in the given word.");
    }else { 
    System.out.println("No of '"+c+ "' present in the given word is " +count(str, c)+"."); 
  }
   
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Given character is not an alphabet");
    }
    
}else{
    System.out.println("Not a valid string");
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OccurrenceOfChar 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a word:"); 
        String word = sc.nextLine(); 
        char [] characterss = word.toCharArray(); 
        for(char ch:characterss)
        {
            if(!Character.isLetter(ch)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid string"); 
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the character: "); 
        char ch = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

        if(Character.isLetter(ch))
        {   
            int count =0;
            for(char chara:characterss)
            {
                if(chara == ch) 
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The given character '"+ch+"' not present in the given word.");              
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No of '"+ch+"' present in the given word is "+count);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Given character is not an alphabet"); 
            Systen.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> C:\Users\Dell\Desktop>java OccurrenceOfChar

> Enter a word:

> Programmer

> Enter the character:

> m

> No of 'm' present in the given word is 2